# npm install and ng serve taking CPU to 100%

Tags: node.js, angular, npm

Recently i have upgraded from angular 8 to angular 11

```
     _                      _                 ____ _     ___
    / \   _ __   __ _ _   _| | __ _ _ __     / ___| |   |_ _|
   / △ \ | '_ \ / _` | | | | |/ _` | '__|   | |   | |    | |
  / ___ \| | | | (_| | |_| | | (_| | |      | |___| |___ | |
 /_/   \_\_| |_|\__, |\__,_|_|\__,_|_|       \____|_____|___|
                |___/


Angular CLI: 11.2.14
Node: 12.22.1
OS: win32 ia32

Angular:
...
Ivy Workspace:

Package                      Version
------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect    0.1102.14 (cli-only)
@angular-devkit/core         11.2.14 (cli-only)
@angular-devkit/schematics   11.2.14 (cli-only)
@schematics/angular          11.2.14 (cli-only)
@schematics/update           0.1102.14 (cli-only)
```

I am facing very strange problem , when i am doing

> npm install its throwing

```
<--- Last few GCs --->

[7924:029AF4A0]   845931 ms: Scavenge 836.1 (849.0) -> 835.8 (856.5) MB, 9.9 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.890, current mu = 0.000) allocation failure
[7924:029AF4A0]   846011 ms: Scavenge 843.7 (856.5) -> 843.1 (856.5) MB, 6.4 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.890, current mu = 0.000) allocation failure
[7924:029AF4A0]   846165 ms: Scavenge 843.7 (856.5) -> 843.0 (862.7) MB, 32.5 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.890, current mu = 0.000) allocation failure


<--- JS stacktrace --->
Cannot get stack trace in GC.
FATAL ERROR: NewSpace::Rebalance Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
```

After multiple attempts even though if i am able to download the node modules. During `npm start` i am getting same error.

Any idea what i can do here ?

Comment: It seems some libs or the code itself changed is making recursion calls. It might be possible due to using diff version. Have you followed the guide provided by Angular?

Answer (score 0):

Well, you're definitely running out of heap.

You can add something like this in your `package.json` under scripts:

```json
scripts: {
  "large-build": "node --max_old_space_size=8048 /node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng build --aot --prod",
  "large-serve": "node --max_old_space_size=8048 ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng serve --aot --prod"
}
```

And you can run it as:

```
npm run large-build
```

and respectively

```
npm run large-serve
```

Comment: is this coming because of migration , what you feel ?

Comment: @Rohitesh - it might be. To be honest, I haven't experienced this on my own side, but I did experience the heap allocation problem.

Comment: @mutankeyboard not able to run using above approach

Comment: 1: 01B09EF4 v8::internal::MicrotaskQueue::kMinimumCapacity+22464 npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE npm ERR! errno 134 npm ERR! pp@1.1.1 large-serve: node --max_old_space_size=8048 ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng serve --proxy-config proxy.conf.json --aot --prod npm ERR! Exit status 134 npm ERR! npm ERR! Failed at the pp@1.1.1 large-serve script. npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.